# How to make POST (API) request with cookies inside controller | Laravel 9.x

Tags: php, laravel, cookies

I'm working with Omada Controller (External Portal Server). That is, to register users through the EAP. The device must be allowed to use WiFi.
I use following documentation:

https://www.tp-link.com/ru/support/faq/3231/
I tested the requests through Postman. Everything is working. However, it is necessary to send a cookie in the request to authorize the device after logging in.

I wrote the following code in Laravel. but cookies are not being stored or sent.

```
public function AuthFree(Request $req)
    {
        $inputs = $req->all();
        //IP Address of Controller
        $endPoint = 'https://CONTROLLER_API:PORT/CONTROLLER_ID/api/v2/hotspot/extPortal/auth';
        $operatorData = self::getCSRFToken();
        $csrfToken = $operatorData->object()->result->token;
        $cookies = $operatorData->cookies()->getCookieByName('TPEAP_SESSIONID')->toArray();//->getValue();
        $deviceBody = [
            'clientMac' => $inputs['clientMac'],
            'apMac' => $inputs['apMac'],
            'ssidName' => $inputs['ssidName'],
            'radioId' => $inputs['radioId'],
            'time' => 1859960742,
            'authType' => 4,
        ];

        $authDevice = Http::withCookies($cookies, $endPoint)
        ->timeout(30)->withOptions([
            'verify' => false,
        ])
        ->withHeaders([
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                'Accept' => 'application/json',
                'Csrf-Token' => $csrfToken,
            ])
            ->post($endPoint, $deviceBody);
        dd($authDevice);
    }

//Login operator.
public function getCSRFToken()
    {
        $authOperator = Http::accept('application/json')->timeout(15)->withOptions([
            'verify' => false,
        ])
            ->post('https://IP:PORT/ID/api/v2/hotspot/login', [
                'name' => 'USERNAME',
                'password' => 'PASSWORD',
            ]);
            
        return $authOperator;
    }
```

Also i wrote as following code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
        // Set return to a value, not return to page
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        // Set up cookies.
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, request()->cookie('TPEAP_SESSIONID'));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, request()->cookie('TPEAP_SESSIONID'));
        // Allow Self Signed Certs
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
        // API Call
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($authInfo));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        $res = curl_exec($ch);
        $resObj = json_decode($res);
        return $resObj;
```

But this also returns error.

The operator enters the system and receives a token through the `getCSRFToken` function mentioned above. A COOKIE is returned along with the token. I need to send TOKEN and COOKIES together to authorize the device.
Meanwhile, the `getCSRFToken` function is running and returning tokens. But `authDevice` is returning an error. Because it can't get Header and Cookies.

My question is: How can I save the cookies and how can I add them to the request and send them?

Is there something wrong with the code I wrote?

Comment: $headers = array(
   "Cookie: Name=Value",
);

Comment: Not this didn't help. Also you send header not cookie.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR and CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE need the same file, so something as:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $temp_cookie_file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,$temp_cookie_file);
```

I'm struggling with the setup of an external portalt too.
Get a token, I can see the TPEAP_SESSIONID in the '$temp_cookie_file', but get in the authorization step: "[errorCode] => -1 [msg] => General error."

Comment: Thanks, I found another way to solve my problem. I did a different solution now and it's working. Authorization and login.